# Player not jumping. Unity RigidBody2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I press my jump key, the player doesn't jump but the Debug message I added does print in console.

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    private Transform transform;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private bool onground = false;

    public float speed;
    public float momentum;
    public float jumpForce;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        transform = rb.transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0, 0);

        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * speed;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && onground)
        {
            Jump(jumpForce);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Floor")
        {
            onground = true;
            Debug.Log("Player Is On Ground!");
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Floor")
        {
            onground = false;
            Debug.Log("Player Is Not On The Ground!");
        }
    }

    private void Jump(float force)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * force * Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log("Player Has Jumped!");
    }
}
```

the player can move but not jump and haven't found any posts anywhere with a similar issue, I might not be looking hard enough or searching the correct thing but I just cannot find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you move the player by `transform` component but trying to jump by physics (`rigidbody`), it isn't a good idea and I recommend you to work only with `rigidbody` in this case. Also the multiply jump force by `Time.deltaTime` doesn't have a sense because you call the method from `FixedUpdate()`, I assume that the power of jump is too week to see the result so try to remove `Time.deltaTime` and increase the `jumpForce` value.